# Path helper methods not available in all RSpec files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm roughly following the [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://railstutorial.org), right now I'm trying to set up a few RSpec tests. This is my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
end
```

I have a `spec/integration/site_layout_spec.rb` file in which I can use helper methods such as `signup_path`:

```
# site_layout_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Root' do
  it 'shows the home page' do
    get signup_path # just to show it's working
    get root_path
    expect(root_path).to render_template('static_pages/home')
  end
end
```

I also have a file `spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb`. In this file, none of the `*_path` helper methods seems to work.

```
# user_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'User signup page' do
  it 'should be available' do
    get signup_path
    expect(signup_path).to exist
  end
end
```

When running `rspec`, I get

```
Failure/Error: get signup_path
NoMethodError: undefined method `signup_path' for nil:NilClass
# ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Why don't the helpers work in my second test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is a controller spec, there you're expected to test controller without routing, by calling it's actions:

```rb
get :new
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you sketch how to adjust my code? Using `get :new` causes another error: `RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.`

Comment: @Pida use `describe UsersController` with class name instead of page, this way rspec will know which class you're testing

Comment: Thanks. I also had to update to use a newer version of RSpec (`~> 4.0.beta`), see [here](https://selleo.com/til/posts/unzexhet61-ruby-on-rails-6-with-rspec-actionviewtemplateerror), and added `expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)` for the actual assertion.